# How to show conditional content based on a dropdown selection? (html+javascript)

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm struggling to show the content based on the dropdown selection in the form. I want text to appear in a div only if "Absolutely" is selected in a select box. Right the text shows up whether or not I select "No way" or "Absolutely".

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="seeAnotherField">Do You Want To See Another Content?</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="seeAnotherField">
          <option value="no">No Way.</option>
          <option value="yes">Absolutely!</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group" id="otherFieldDiv">
    This text should show up if "Absolutely"
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$("#seeAnotherField").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "yes") {
    $('#otherFieldDiv').show();
    $('#otherField').attr('required', '');
    $('#otherField').attr('data-error', 'This field is required.');
  } else {
    $('#otherFieldDiv').hide();
    $('#otherField').removeAttr('required');
    $('#otherField').removeAttr('data-error');
  }
});
$("#seeAnotherField").trigger("change");

</script>
```

Comment: if I understand correctly, works as you already wanted? and where is the #otherField1 and #otherField2?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It shows the content no matter which selection I make in a select box. I want to show content on the page only if "Absolutely" is selected.

Comment: Apologies, I edited the code. So "otherfield" is in question.

Comment: When Absolutely! is already selected, the following div appears. Open new html and add this code + script src and try pls

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Actually I didn't understand you. You wanted show div when x selected and that work in my local with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am far from proficient with `jQuery` but I was able to get the show/hide working on like this. Initially set the display of the target DIV to none so it will not appear until it is requested by the change function. The `show()` or `hide()` methods set the inline style for `display` which overrides whatever is defined in css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <title>Toggle visibility</title>
        <style>
            .reveal{display:none}
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).on('ready',function(){
                $('select').on('change',function(e){
                    switch( $(this).val() ){
                        case 'yes':
                            $('.reveal').show();
                            $('.reveal input').each( function(i,n){
                                n.required=true;
                                n.dataset.error='This field is required.';
                            })
                        break;
                        case 'no':
                            $('.reveal').hide();
                            $('.reveal input').each( function(i,n){
                                n.removeAttribute('required');
                                n.dataset.error=false;
                            })
                        break;
                    }
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <form>
        
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label>
                    Do You Want To See Another Content?
                    <select class='form-control'>
                        <option value='no'>No Way.
                        <option value='yes'>Absolutely!
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class='form-group reveal'>
                This text should show up if 'Absolutely' is selected!
                <input type='text' name='important_data' value='banana' />
                <input type='text' name='more_important_data' value='apple' />
                <input type='text' name='even_more_important_data' value='cherry' />
            </div>
            
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but this isn't working for me, the text doesn't show up when Absolutely is selected

Comment: Are you seeing errors in the console? Have you tried exactly as above?